# asp.net MVC 3 layout pages not created by ViewPageActivator (bug??)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, razor

I use a custom ViewPageActivator (registered with a custom DependencyResolver) that I use to instantiate my views so I can inject dependecies, but I noticed it isn't used to instantiate the layout pages. Is this a bug? It's preventing me from initializing my custom helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design. Technically speaking the concept of layout pages is a feature of ASP.NET WebPages and MVC is not concerned with how they are instantiated. This works the same as the Master pages in the Aspx view engine.

Comment: So how do I inject dependencies so I can initialize the helpers in the layout pages?